# How do I get a CSS arrow to appear next to my table header?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to use CSS to get a small up or down arrow to appear next to a cell in my table header but the arrow is appearing on top of my header and it seems much larger than the 20 pixels I thought it would be at the base.

```css
.headerRow {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table id="searchResults">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th class="headerRaceName arrow-down" data-order="name">Event</th>
      <th class="headerYear" data-order="day">Yr</th>
      <th class="headerDate" data-order="day">Date</th>
      <th class="headerDistance">Distance</th>
      <th class="headerLocation" data-order="location">Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

What am I missing in order to get the arrow to appear neatly to the right of my table header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: moved the arrow to the right.*

Well 20px is half the size of the arrow, so if you want your arrow to be 20px wide it should be 10px. And if you want text inside the `th`, you should use a pseudo element instead of modifying the `th` itself. See demo:

```css
.arrow-down:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table id="searchResults">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th class="headerRaceName arrow-down" data-order="name">Event </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

A good way to understand the css arrow trick is to give each border a different color. I'm sure as soon as you see the result you can easily understand why the border width must be 10px to get a 20px wide arrow:

```css
.arrow-down:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid yellow;
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table id="searchResults">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th class="headerRaceName arrow-down" data-order="name">Event </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```